# Selecting the most popular entry from the last ten values entered

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the selecting from the last ten entries working, but am unsure how to get the most popular from these ten entries? Also how would I count the number of the most popular entry & output it to a percentage?

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT data FROM table_answers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"; 
    $result = mysql_query ($sql, $db); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) 
    { 
         echo "[".$row['data']."]"; 
    } 
?>
```

And I have tried to do the WHERE value as well but it doesn't return any result.

```
$sql = "SELECT data FROM table_answers WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_answers
         ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$result = mysql_query ($sql, $db); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) 
    { 
        echo " [".$row['data']."] ";  
    }
```

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here? please

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve the problem -

```
SELECT tableorder.* 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM table
      ORDER BY id DESC 
      LIMIT 10) tableorder 
ORDER BY tableorder.popularity DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

The inner query will sort on the basis on id and get the top 10. The outer will again sort the 10 rows on the basis of popularity and return the row with highest popularity.

Comment: tableorder is just an alias to the inner SELECT as it is behaving as a table for the outer SELECT.
For the percentage try this - SELECT dataandcount.data, 
     dataandcount.count*10
FROM (SELECT tableorder.data, 
          COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM
        (SELECT * 
      FROM table
      ORDER BY id DESC 
      LIMIT 10) tableorder
      GROUP BY tableorder.data) dataandcount
ORDER BY dataandcount.popularity DESC 
LIMIT 1;

dataandcount in this is again an alias given to the table. I am not sure of the performance of this query but I think this will solve your purpose.

Comment: Corrected the above query. SELECT dataandcount.data, dataandcount.count*10 FROM (SELECT tableorder.data, COUNT(*) AS count FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) tableorder GROUP BY tableorder.data) dataandcount ORDER BY dataandcount.count DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: If you add another SELECT over it and multiply the count with 10 it will give the percentage (count * 100 / 10 = count * 10). While doing so you should order by count to get the highest percent.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT data
FROM (
    SELECT data
    FROM table_answers
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10
) t
ORDER BY popularity
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still won't work for me.

`$sql = "SELECT data
FROM (
    SELECT data
    FROM table_answers
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10
) t
ORDER BY popularity";

$result = mysql_query ($sql, $db); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) 
       { 
            echo "        [".$row['data']."]       "; 

       }`